# Android Studio not checking Java files into GitHub

Tags: android, git, github, android-studio

I am using Android Studio and checking in my files.  Everything works fine, except the main.java files are not committing at all.  I have tried to go through each file and push the commit and add button.  Android Studio says "all files are up to date," but when I look inside GitHub, nothing is there except the folder.

I have looked at the ignore file and the files are not located inside of this.

Comment: Have you pushed your files up to the server? Committing only commits them locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue, I was not able to fix it elegantly but I was able to commit my project to a new repository. First start by deleting the .git folder inside the project folder. Also make sure to check under your Java folders for any .git folders. These, I believe, are hidden by default so you'll have enable show hidden files. After this, go back to Android Studio and it will tell you some changes have occurred, go ahead and click 'Configure'. It will open up the settings window, delete those items in red text. It should now be ready so that you can import into version control from the beginning. I personally, used these steps https://www.londonappdeveloper.com/how-to-use-git-hub-with-android-studio/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to look into Changes View Window. Make a change to any of the .java files and have a look at the Changes view Window. Check whether the changed file gets listed there. If it's not listed

- I believe you have not added the folder in which java files exits into your repo

Other option is to manually add the files from Command Line once and do the above steps again and check.